# Getting "DSO missing from command line" with custom glibc

Tags: gcc, glibc

I am trying to link a program with a custom GLIBC installation. I have tried the following options, but got the same error

```
objs/ngx_modules.o \
-Wl,--emit-relocs -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/opt/glibc-2.23-install/lib/ld-2.23.so -ldl -Wl,-rpath-link,/opt/glibc-2.23-install/lib -lcrypt -lpcre -lz \
-Wl,-E
/usr/bin/ld: objs/src/core/ngx_shmtx.o: undefined reference to symbol 'sem_post@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/opt/glibc-2.23-install/lib/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

and

```
objs/ngx_modules.o \
-Wl,--emit-relocs -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/opt/glibc-2.23-install/lib/ld-2.23.so -ldl -L/opt/glibc-2.23-install/lib -lcrypt -lpcre -lz \
-Wl,-E
/usr/bin/ld: objs/src/core/ngx_shmtx.o: undefined reference to symbol 'sem_post@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
objs/Makefile:226: recipe for target 'objs/nginx' failed
```

and

```
objs/ngx_modules.o \
-Wl,--emit-relocs -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/opt/glibc-2.23-install/lib/ld-2.23.so -ldl -L/opt/glibc-2.23-install/lib/libpthread.so -lcrypt -lpcre -lz \
-Wl,-E
/usr/bin/ld: objs/src/core/ngx_shmtx.o: undefined reference to symbol 'sem_post@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
objs/Makefile:226: recipe for target 'objs/nginx' failed
```

Any alternative then?

Answer (score 0):

> `-Wl,--emit-relocs -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/opt/glibc-2.23-install/lib/ld-2.23.so -ldl -L/opt/glibc-2.23-install/lib/libpthread.so -lcrypt -lpcre -lz \
>   -Wl,-E`

Furious activity is no substitute for understanding. The command you want:

```
gcc objs/ngx_modules.o  \
  -Wl,-E -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/opt/glibc-2.23-install/lib/ld-2.23.so \
  -L/opt/glibc-2.23-install/lib \
  -lcrypt -lpcre -lz -lpthread
```